# Writing to window from child process in ncurses

Tags: c, fork, ncurses, child-process

I'm attempting to write a program in which a child process is spawned and takes charge of all the visual part (with ncurses) I've initialized all the ncurses stuff in the parent (before the fork), because I couldn't get it to work when doing it from the child, and the intial things show. But when it's time for the child process to write things on the screen, it seems to be completely ignored.

What do I need to do for the children to be able to write to a window?

I can post my code if needed, but I have a feeling this is probably something very obvious that I overlooked.

Comment: normally you'd pass information like that via a [pipe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html), and make the parent process manage the display.

Comment: @ThomasDickey then I would need to keep the parent process occupied instead of doing something else right? It’s a requirement for me to use a child to manage output and do other things with the parent